# Ardor 2.0.7e Crashes on Startup - Java Heap Space Issue

Tags: wallet, nxt, server, ardor

Previous ardor versions worked fine. Just installed Ardor 2.0.7e on my ubuntu 14.04 and 512mb ram system. But I'm getting a java heap space error. I'm assuming its a memory issue. How can this be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by starting up the ardor service with the following parameters: -Xmx256M

```
./run.bat -Xmx256M
```

By default 256mb setting is turned off. By adding in those options to run.bat it reduces the requirements to 256mb only.